# How many bits does a data bus need to have?

Tags: computer-architecture

Using the following context as an example for the calculations:

> **Data bus** connecting the processor to a memory **32 bits**, considering a memory with capacity of **16kB**.

---

### How many bits does a data bus need to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the bus is multiplexed, every data bit is conveyed by a distinct data line, hence $32$.

This does not account for the address bus.